# Conda error when using Jupyter notebook (DLL load failed while importing _device: The file cannot be accessed by the system.)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have a project that requires using python =3.8.5, jupyter_client =6.1.12 and pywin32=300. I have python 3.10 installed on my computer. I decided to set up conda environment with Jupyter Notebook in miniconda. First,
I created a conda environment

```
conda create -n testenv python=3.8.5
```

then i activated the env

```
conda activate testenv
```

once in the testenv environment, i installed packages using pip

```
pip install jupyter jupyter_client==6.1.12 pywin32==300
```

last i type the command

```
jupyter notebook
```

However I received the following error message

File "C:\Users..\Miniconda3\envs\testenv\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_*init*_.py", line 6, in 
from . import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _device: The file cannot be accessed by the system.

Does anyone know what might be the issue? Thank you!

Comment: Why not just `conda create -n testenv -c conda-forge python=3.8.5 jupyter jupyter_client=6.1.12 pywin32=300`?

Comment: Previously i was using python 3.10 and after downgrading to 3.9 there's no longer issue.